# How do I use FireWire drives in a VMWare Windows XP virtual machine on my Mac?

Tags: windows-xp, vmware, firewire

I’ve got a Windows XP vitual machine running in VMWare 2 on my Mac.

I can get USB drives to show up in the virtual machine, by selecting them in the “USB Devices” section of “Removable Devices” in the VM’s settings, when the VM is on. But I can’t see an equivalent option for FireWire drives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a FireWire drive to show up as a drive (as opposed to a shared folder) in a VMWare Windows XP virtual machine on my Mac?](http://superuser.com/questions/176917/how-do-i-get-a-firewire-drive-to-show-up-as-a-drive-as-opposed-to-a-shared-folde)

Comment: @heavyd — That’s a subtly different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! As long as the FireWire drive is formatted with a Windows-readable filesystem, it’ll show up as a shared folder in VMWare Shared Folders.