# How do I get a FireWire drive to show up as a drive (as opposed to a shared folder) in a VMWare Windows XP virtual machine on my Mac?

Tags: windows-xp, vmware-fusion, firewire

I’ve got a Windows XP vitual machine running in VMWare 2 on my Mac.

I’ve got a FireWire drive with a Windows-readable partition on it plugged into my Mac. This Windows partition shows up in the Windows XP virtual machine as a shared folder.

Is there any way I can make the partition show up in Windows XP as a drive instead? (E.g. the G: drive.) I need to do this because I’ve got a USB external drive that I need to clone to the FireWire drive. I can’t do this unless the FireWire drive can show up in Windows as a drive, rather than just a folder.

I’ve tried mapping the folder it shows up as to a drive, but this doesn’t make it show up as a destination option when cloning the USB drive. (I’m using Acronis TrueImage for cloning.)

Comment: please consider next time editing your original question with additional details rather than posting and almost identical question.

Comment: @heavyd — I see your point, but they are different questions. One’s about accessing the contents of external drive (which I realised how to do), whereas this one’s about setting it up as a drive in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to tell your Mac *not* to mount the drive, and configure VMWare to use direct disk access rather than than filesystem access to make this drive available to the guest OS.